# Can't connect to network using ethernet at work

Tags: windows, networking

I have a problem with my wifi card and need to connect to my office network with ethernet cable but when I unplug the cable from the office PC and conect it to my own nothing happens, it doesn't even ask me for authentication. If I manually configure the IP it tries to connect over and over again but nothing happens. It's a windows network. Could you help me please?

Comment: ask your IT admin

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely NOT allowed to connect your own equipment and there are technical measures in place to prevent that.
(If the WIFI is normally open to everybody it is probably not directly connected to the office LAN and there is an additional security layer between the WIFI and the office LAN.)

Talk to your IT admin and ask if you can connect your own stuff.
And, if it is allowed, how to do it.

Comment: As Tonny states, secure networks allow only known machines to connect. At a facility at which I worked, during a presentation, an instructor from a university connected his laptop using an employee's IP, and an IT technician along with an armed guard showed up, annoyed.